# Rosbag record in unexisting folder

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I would like to know if anyone knows a solution when we record in a folder with rosbag, but that folder doesn't exist....

In my case, I found that rosbag just doesn't seems to save anything... But without any error message ! And that's a big problem, because my recording was just a "one shot" thing....

Is there any way to find the data somewhere ? (I tried ~/.ros, but nothing there)...

Thank you very much !

Stéphane

EDIT : if you launch rosbag record from a launch file, you have to let

```
output="screen"
```

otherwise the error message doesn't appears.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61382/rosbag-record-in-unexisting-folder/) by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1304 on 2013-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-04-23**:
How did you manage to record to a directory that doesn't exist? Did you delete the working directory where you ran rosbag while rosbag was running?

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-04-23**:
In fact, imagine I want to record in /home/data folder. So I recorded some things, saved them on an hard drive, but by doing that, I removed the folder data. When I relaunch rosbag record, nothing is saved, as the folder doesn't exist anymore.

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-04-23**:
And rosbag then behave "as if it was recording", without letting us know it's not recording at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To sum up my understanding of what happened: You started `rosbag record` in `/home/data`, and while rosbag was recording, you deleted that directory. The question is whether rosbag should print an error message if you do that. (Please correct me if I misunderstood your question.)

That's not a bug in rosbag, but a general design decision in Unix. As long as rosbag is still running, you can try to recover the file from `/proc/pid/fd`, otherwise maybe [this](http://carlo17.home.xs4all.nl/howto/undelete_ext3.html) will help (more information [here](http://glandium.org/blog/?p=87)).

BTW: If you delete `/home/data` *before* starting rosbag, you'll get an error saying that the file is not writable; only if you delete it while rosbag is recording, you'll lose the data.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-04-23**:
No. I deleted the /home/data before starting rosbag. And I didn't get any error. Maybe it is because it is inside a launch file ? Example : " "

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-04-23**:
But anyway, thank you for your answer, it helped me to understand :-)

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-04-23**:
I made an test by adding output="screen" and indeed, it shows an error message... (I desactivated it because my launch files launch so many things that I only keep the interesting messages shown...). Thank you again, have a good day !

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-04-23**:
Glad I could help! :-)